# .htaccess issue php $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] is empty

Tags: php, apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On local host I was running my php (MVC) application with following rules in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^(config|core|css|js|fonts|images|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

E.g. `localhost/myapp/register/login` will load the log in page.
But on a live server, I'm having issues. The first problem I've faced was `No input file specified`. Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557258/htaccess-issues-no-input-file-specified) I changed this line `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`. This solved the first problem but created another problem and now it's always loading the same/default view and controller no matter what the URL is.

My index.php has the following lines of code:

```
$url = isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? explode('/', ltrim($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '/')) : [];
 // Route the request
 Router::route($url);
```

So, I checked the $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] value and it's empty. Now my question is why it's empty and how can i achieve the normal behavior of the URLs.

Comment: If you changed the rule to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]` then yes, there will be no path-info because you've changed it to use a query string instead?! (Why are you converting the path-info into an array of _path segments_?)

Comment: @MrWhite I'm converting the path-info into an array of path segments because I need to load the required Controller and action inside my Router class. For example: if the requested URL is `http://example.com/home/index` then `home` is the controller class and `index` is the action.

Comment: "No input file specified" would seem to be triggered by your application - what does this have to do with `.htaccess`?

Comment: @MrWhite seems that I've to add   `?` after `index.php`  in the `RewriteRule` which is causing the problem.

Comment: Finally I made it work. My new `RewriteRule` is `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]. I'm using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']`  in my `index.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Finally I made it work. My new `RewriteRule` is `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`. I'm using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` in my `index.php`.

If you are using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in your PHP code then you probably shouldn't be appending a query string (containing the URL-path) to the `RewriteRule` *substitution* (at least you don't *need* to), ie. Simply use `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` instead.

The `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` PHP superglobal contains the requested URL-path only, regardless of your `RewriteRule` directive. This also contains a potential query string (which, strictly speaking you should probably split in your PHP code). (Unlike the Apache server variable of the same name that only contains the URL-path.)

---

If instead you chose to pass a query string, as in your "changed" `RewriteRule`, then you don't appear to need to add the slash prefix (since you remove this in your PHP code). For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Then, in `index.php` you would have:

```
$url = !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? explode('/',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) : [];
```

Note that `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is *always* set, hence the need to check for `!empty()`, rather than `isset()`.

Comment: I'm new in the `.htaccess` world and learning a lot from the pros like you @MrWhite. Thanks again for the answer. I'll go with your first suggestion.